# One command-line in python to automatize code

Tags: python, function, machine-learning

I am newbie in Python. I am using it for machine learning in EEG.
This is my function to extract the "features". 
Is there a way to improve it? I mean, I don't want to be changing the frequencies each time I need other range. So, in PART B you'll see my attempt.

PART A

```
def computePowerBands(f, amp):
    return (np.mean(amp[(f >= 0.5)*(f <= 4.5)]),
            np.mean(amp[(f >= 4.5)*(f <= 8.5)]),
            np.mean(amp[(f >= 8.5)*(f <= 11.5)]),
            np.mean(amp[(f >= 11.5)*(f <= 15.5)]),
            np.mean(amp[(f >= 15.5)*(f <= 32.5)]) )
```

PART B

```
def computePowerBands(f, amp, fce):
    return (np.mean(amp[k * k for k in fce]))
```

Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: (f >= 0.5)*(f <= 4.5) returns either 0 or 1 (presuming f is a number).  Each of those expressions is boolean, and multiplying is effectively a logical `and` so you are indexing amp with either 0 or 1 each time.  what does fce look like?

Comment: PART B squares each value in **fce** and feeds that list as an index to **amp**.  If **amp** is a np vector, this will give you a vector as input to **mean**.  However, I question whether that's what you really want to do.

Comment: @GarrettR Also to note is that `bool` is a subclass of `int`. `False == 0` and `True == 1`. So yes, multiplication of `bool`s is actually an `and` which will cause either element `0` or `1` to be accessed in `amp`.

Comment: @Kupiakos yeah, i realize.  just a slightly obfuscated way of achieving that.  Just making sure that's what OP intended?

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve, as it is really obfuscated chunk of code, but by simple code refactoring you can parametrize it through the list of pairs:

```
def computePowerBands(f, amp, fce):
    return [np.mean(amp[(f >= low)*(f <= up)]) for low, up in fce]
```

and call it with

```
computePowerBands(f, amp, [(0.5, 4.5), (4.5, 8.5)])
```

and so on.

Or if the following bands always share ends:

```
def computePowerBands(f, amp, fce):
    return [np.mean(amp[(f >= fce[fid])*(f <= fce[fid+1])])
            for fid in range(len(fce)-1)]
```

and call it with

```
computePowerBands(f, amp, [0.5, 4.5, 8.5])
```